# How to debug Java with command argument in IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm learning SedgeWick's 《algorithm4》and I often need to debug the code in the book. but I can't run or debug directly by IDE button because there have many example code need set args in command line like:

```
java -cp ../../algs4.jar RandomSeq.java 20 50 60
java -cp ../../algs4.jar BinarySearch.java tinyW.txt < tinyY.txt
```

[image]

I want to debug java class with command args but I have no idea how to make it.

Comment: You seem to be starting your Java application manually from the built-in Terminal in IntelliJ IDEA. This means you're not really using the Java capabilities of IDEA at all. You should instead launch it via a [Run/debug configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration.html). There you can specify command line arguments if you like and then launch it either in "normal" mode or "debug" mode. If you just click "run" on a class, it will create a launch configuration for you that you can then edit to include the arguments that you want.

Comment: Thanks,that solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use Run/Debug Configuration for [Java Application](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/running-applications.html#quick-way) and specify a `Main class` and `Program arguments` in the Run Configuration dialog:

[image]